# How to adjust xul's datepicker arrows size?

Tags: css, xul

Using the css:

```
datepicker {
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

I can have a time [datepicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/datepicker) with big font, but I would like the arrow (up and down) in the right side of the component were big also. Is there a way?

Comment: If I'm recalling correctly, using Firebug to Inspect the element should give you the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker arrows are normally styled with native appearance but it might be possible to adjust their size, the class name is `spinbuttons-button`.

Comment: Also, for who is interested, the `spinbuttons-box` is the outer box, with 2 `spinbuttons-button`. I just realized that it is defined at a file called `spinbuttons.xml`.